# What's the most up-to-date way to capture an iSight/FaceTime camera image on the Mac?

Tags: macos, cocoa, camera, isight

I would like to present a camera preview in my app, that takes a photo when you click a button. The documentation for `AVFoundation` looked largely iOS-specific, even on the Mac docs site. `QTKit` looked like it would do what I need, but it's also an older framework.

Starting a new app today, requiring OS X 10.10, what are the trade-offs of using either library, and might it be a concern that `QTKit` is older (perhaps it might be deprecated soon)? I also consider it a goal for the code to be as concise and expressvie as possible.

Answer (score 0):

According to Apple, [`AVFoundation` is the preferred framework going forward](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/technotes/tn2300/_index.html). `QTKit` has at least softly been deprecated.